# How to connect ec2 with local database

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Let me start suppose my local network system which I want to connect from EC2 using VPC. Now my question is that if I provide public IP address of local system network then it will disconnect, if IP address change how I can manage this? I want EC2 and local network talk with each other with single IP. Below is few things which I follow to create VPN in AWS:

1. In VPC I had provide a random CIDR range
2. In customer gateway I provided a public IP address of local system network (here is confusing part I want both system talk with each other using single IP of local system network what happened if public IP of local system network change how I can manage)
3. Virtual private network in this I just gave a name and attached it with VPC
4. In VPN I connect step 1 ,2 and 3 and provide static IP address range eg `10.0.0.16/32` here is also I have confusion suppose I have node server in my EC2 and database at local system network. In config I just provide single IP address of local system to connect DB. So how my node server and DB connect maintained connection even if public IP address change?

Can any one clear my doubt and suggest me all above step which I had followed is correct or I missed something?

Comment: You may consider Elastic IP for maintaining the same IP.

Comment: @MichałUrbaniak thanks for your replay, can know step which i follow is correct and what use of CIDR

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your comment to be honest

Comment: @MichałUrbaniak sorry, I mean step which I had to follow (describe above for vpn) is this correct way